# OCMock Class Method Not Working

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying to mock a class method that identifies if the iOS is iOS 6 (or earlier) or iOS 7 (or later). Here is the testing code:

```
id iOSDetectorMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UTiOSVersionDetector class]];
[[[iOSDetectorMock stub] andReturnValue:@(YES)] isIOS6_Earlier];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];
[self.homeViewController loadView];
[self.homeViewController viewDidLoad];
XCTAssertTrue([self.homeViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor isEqual:Color_Dark_Green], @"Navigation bar tint color is not correct");
[iOSDetectorMock stopMocking];
navController = nil;
```

However, the method `isIOS6_Earlier` keeps on returning NO neglecting the mock I used. The original code of `UTiOSVersionDetector` is below:

```
+ (BOOL) isIOS6_Earlier {

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] <= 6) {
    return YES;
}

return NO;

}
```

Edit: I am testing on Xcode 5.1, yet it exists on Xcode 5.0.2 too.

Comment: Does using the provided `OCMOCK_VALUE()` macro yield better results? The macro creates an `NSValue`, which is different from the `NSNumber` you are passing

Comment: Same results, no difference.

Comment: This should work. In the code you posted it's not clear how the controllers are created. Is it possible that they call the `isIO6_earlier` method when they are created, before the stub is set up?

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg I updated the code to clear it out. Still not working. The viewDidLoad method is the one detecting the iOS and changing the color according to it.

Comment: With the code you posted: [[iOSDetectorMock stub] andReturnValue:@(NO)] isIOS6_Earlier] the mock will always return NO. Or are you using [.. andReturnValue:@YES] in your actual test code?

Comment: @MichałCiuba Sorry, a copy paste mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: Maybe try to make it more explicit: [[[[iOSDetectorMock stub] classMethod] andReturnValue:@YES] isIOS6_Earlier]. As described on http://ocmock.org/features/, it can be helpful in some cases.

Comment: Are you sure the mock is being called? If you use an "andDo" block and set a break point in the block, do you see it stop there? Is it possible that the logic in your VC is actually broken?

Comment: @MichałCiuba yes, it worked as you said. Please, post it as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try to make it more explicit:

```
[[[[iOSDetectorMock stub] classMethod] andReturnValue:@YES] isIOS6_Earlier];
```

As described on [ocmock.org/features](http://ocmock.org/features), it can be helpful in some cases.